# jquery passing variable to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

when i try get and echo the variable on php, sending by ajax, i receive always var_dump null

the alert is ok, he shows the current slide id number when <a>(role=button) prev or next is clicked: 1 on slide 1, 2 on 2, 3 on 3;

```
<script>
$("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  var value1 = $(this).find('.carousel-item.active').attr('id');
  alert(value1);
  var value = {
    idCarrosselAtivo: $(this).find('.carousel-item.active').attr('id')
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "teste.php",
    data: value,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
})
</script>
    
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['idCarrosselAtivo'])&& $_POST['idCarrosselAtivo'] === 'c1') {
        echo $idCarrossel;
    } else {
      var_dump($idCarrossel);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You never assign `$idCarrossel = $_POST['idCarroselAtivo'];`

Comment: Why do you assign `value1` but then repeat the expression instead of using the variable? Use `idCarrosselAtivo: value1`

Comment: i will fix it and try again, but all the rest make sense?? I just was trying another way, thats why

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example.

**jQuery**

```
$("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  console.log("Sending ", $(this).find('.carousel-item.active').attr('id'));
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "teste.php",
    data: {
      idCarrosselAtivo: $(this).find('.carousel-item.active').attr('id')
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['idCarrosselAtivo'])){
    $idCarrossel = $_POST['idCarrosselAtivo'];
    if($idCarrossel === 'c1') {
      echo $idCarrossel;
    } else {
      var_dump($_POST['idCarrosselAtivo']);
    }
  }
?>
```

It's not clear why you are sending back the ID when you just sent it to the script. This will send the ID and get some PHP back.

Comment: I think the "why" is just that it's a simple example to test that data is flowing properly.